# Django Rest Framework AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have been trying to add attributes to the UserProfile by creating a `OneToOneField` to User and adding different fields. Now I run this and call the api with the body below. The api is able to successfully get parsed. A user gets created in the user table and user profile table with the correct attributes. However, Django returns an error `AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field first_name on serializer UserProfileSerializer`. This makes sense since the model does not have these attributes, but what is the correct way to pass the json in the same manner and create the user in the `User` Table and `UserProfile` Table?

```json
{
    "first_name": "Jay",
    "last_name" : "Patel",
    "email": "tes1t@email.com",
    "password": "password",
    "tier": "Gold",
    "bkms_id": "12234"
}
```

model.py

```py
# Create your models here.
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    MedalType: List[Tuple[str, str]] = [('Bronze', 'Bronze'), ('Silver', 'Silver'), ('Gold', 'Gold')]
    bkms_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    tier = models.CharField(choices=MedalType, max_length=100)
    user = models.OneToOneField(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

serializer.py

```py
from typing import Dict

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers

from authentication.models import UserProfile


class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=65, min_length=8, write_only=True, required=True,
                                     style={'input_type': 'password'})
    email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=255, min_length=4, required=True)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, min_length=2, required=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, min_length=2, required=True)
    bkms_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=True, min_value=0)
    tier = serializers.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'bkms_id', 'tier']

    def validate(self, attrs):
        if User.objects.filter(email=attrs.get('email', '')).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'email': 'Email is already in use'})
        if UserProfile.objects.filter(bkms_id=attrs.get('bkms_id', '')).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'bkms_id': 'BKMS is already in use'})
        return super().validate(attrs)

    def create(self, validated_data: Dict):
        email = validated_data.pop('email', '')
        password = validated_data.pop('password', '')
        first_name = validated_data.pop('first_name', '')
        last_name = validated_data.pop('last_name', '')
        user = User.objects.create_user(email, email, password, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
        user.save()
        validated_data['user'] = user
        return UserProfile.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

views.py

```py
# Create your views here.
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.generics import GenericAPIView
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from rest_framework.response import Response

from authentication.serializers import UserProfileSerializer


class RegisterView(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserProfileSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating different serializers like this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=65, min_length=8, write_only=True, required=True,
                                     style={'input_type': 'password'})
    email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=255, min_length=4, required=True)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, min_length=2, required=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, min_length=2, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password']

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    bkms_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=True, min_value=0)
    tier = serializers.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['user', 'bkms_id', 'tier']

    def validate(self, attrs):
        if User.objects.filter(email=attrs.get('email', '')).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'email': 'Email is already in use'})
        if UserProfile.objects.filter(bkms_id=attrs.get('bkms_id', '')).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'bkms_id': 'BKMS is already in use'})
        attrs['user'] = {
           'email': attrs.get('email', ''),
           'first_name': attrs.get('first_name', ''),
           'last_name': attrs.get('last_name', ''),
           'password': attrs.get('password', '')
        }
        return super().validate(attrs)

    def create(self, validated_data: Dict):
       validated_user = validated_data.pop('user', {})
       email = validated_user.pop('email', '')
       password = validated_user.pop('password', '')
       first_name = validated_user.pop('first_name', '')
       last_name = validated_user.pop('last_name', '')
       user = User.objects.create_user(email=email, password=password, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
       user.save()
       validated_data['user'] = user
       return UserProfile.objects.create(**validated_data)
```